# Change of variables in the Weierstrass form $y^2=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6$ for the generic fiber

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I'm reading [Schütt-Shioda](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aspm/1543085637)'s survey paper on elliptic surfaces, section "Tate's algorithm".

My question doesn't concern the algorithm itself, but only the initial manipulation the authors do on the Weierstrass equation.

If $f:S\to C$ is an elliptic fibration, the generic fiber and $\Delta$ are given by:
$$y^2=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6$$
$$\Delta=-27a_6^2+18a_2a_4a_6+a_2^2a_4^2-4a_2^3a_6-4a_4^3$$

We want to analyze when $\Delta=0$. We take a local parameter $t$ in $C$ and a valuation $v$ with $v(t)=1$, so $\Delta(0)=0$ is equivalent to $v(\Delta)>0$.

The author then says: "by a translation in $x$, we can move the singularity to $(0,0)$. Then the extended Weierstrass form transforms as $y^2=x^3+a_2x^2+ta'_4x+ta_6'$".

I don't understand how the translation is done. If we translate $x$ by $\lambda$, we get a new Weierstrass equation with free term $\lambda^3+a_2\lambda^2+a_4\lambda+a_6$, which is zero iff $\lambda$ is a root of $T^3+a_2T^2+a_4T+a_6$. But the existence of such $\lambda$ is highly dependent on the field, right? Besides, assuming this is possible, I do understand why we change $a_6$ for $ta_6'$, but not why we change $a_4$ for $ta_4'$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the authors' use of this local parameter $t$. Is $t$ a place of the function field $K(C)$? Or a place of the base $S$? Anyway, let's just assume we've base changed the curve to the residue field of $t$, so everything I write is true mod $t$.

Comment: For the first question: Let $f(x) = x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6$. If $P = (r,s)$ is a singular point of $y^2 = f(x)$, then by computing partial derivatives we have $2s = f'(r) = 0$, so $s=0$. Then $P = (r,0)$, so $r$ is a root of $f$.

In order to move the singular point to $(0,0)$, let $u = x-r$. Rewriting $f(x)$ in terms of $u$, we have
\begin{align*}
f(u+r) = u^3 + (3r + a_2) x^2 + \overbrace{(3 r^2 + 2r a_2 + a_4)}^{a_4'}x + r^3 + r^2 a_2 + r a_4 + a_6 \, .
\end{align*}
Then $a_4' = f'(r) = 0$.